# broken screen? Acer aspire laptop

Tags: display

I was abroad and recently received my laptop from shipping. it had obviously been damaged in transit. I turned it on and only the top third of the screen was visible. It has since deteriorated to being all white. Some areas are highly pixelated.

I was just wondering if anyone knew the cause of this? Is it just the screen which has been damaged?
Thanks very much for any help or suggestions

Comment: It's just the screen. Otherwise, the POST would have caught the error (if it was caused by a broken hard drive/cpu/memory)

Comment: I don't understand these posts from people with brand new products, you have 1. at least a 1 year warranty, 2. its less than 30 days before you bought it, why arnt you talking to Acer Customer Support to get a replacement. This isn't a rant, i'm just trying to understand your logic.

Comment: @Sickest - I agree. Q: I bought a new thing. It's broken. What should I do?. A: Contact the vendor.